# Performing complex joins using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

We were tasked to do this challenge:

**Challenge! Find the actor who is the actor_1_name for the movie that grossed exactly 67344392. Then, find films whose actor_3_name is Piolo Pascual and actor_1_name is the person from Armageddon.**

I first imported pandas and read the metadata

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('movie_metadata.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

And, I already did the first task with this code

```
## Find the actor who is the actor_1_name for the movie that grossed exactly 67344392
data[data.gross == 67344392]['actor_1_name']
```

However, I am now hopelessly stuck with the second task "Then, find films whose actor_3_name is Piolo Pascual and actor_1_name is the person from Armageddon." I did this code initially,

```
data1 = data.actor_1_name[data.movie_title == 'Armageddon']
data[(data['actor_3_name'] == 'Piolo Pascual') &
     (data['actor_1_name'] == str(data1))]
data.movie_title[(data.actor_3_name == 'Piolo Pascual') &
                 (data.actor_1_name == str(bruce))]
```

but I only get an ouput of "Series([], Name: movie_title, dtype: object)"

Where did I go wrong? I need concrete help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an empty series as output which means filters are not applied correctly. Maybe you can try below change

```
# Below command will give the name of the actor_1_name
data1 = data.actor_1_name[data.movie_title == 'Armageddon'].value[0]

# Replace bruse with data1 bcz i am not sure when variable bruse was assigned
data.movie_title[(data.actor_3_name == 'Piolo Pascual') &
                 (data.actor_1_name == str(data1))]

#or
data1 = data.actor_1_name[data.movie_title == 'Armageddon']
data.movie_title[(data.actor_3_name == 'Piolo Pascual') &
                 (data.actor_1_name.isin(data1))
                ]
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I actually got it already, I just forgot to delete. Btw, I used tolist() function then compared the data by assigning the armageddon actor to the index  0. Anyways, thank you, still!